# Add Close button to Chart in excel add in

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-charts

I am working on Excel Add-in and need to show some charts to user. Issue I am facing is that there is no close button on charts and users wants to have some button on chart which can close/hide it. I am unable to find any such option in Office.js and Excel JS API. Can anyone guide me how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do anything in an add-in that cannot be done by a user through the Excel interface. Since Excel charts don't have a hide/close button, you can't programmatically put such a button charts. The user can remove a chart following the instructions here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/delete-a-chart-eea1ec2f-fc41-4a8d-ba4b-fcdc7b12d9bf

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Now if we can not add close button, then can we use Chart in a dialog box? So that I can show same chart in dialog box?

Comment: An Excel chart can only appear on an Excel worksheet. If you wanted to have a chart in a dialog, you would have to create all the graphics code to render the chart. It would be a massive job.